# How to pick React JS form input field value using Axios

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I am creating a form in react js and need to pick input field values using Axios.

```
 axios({ 
        method: 'post', 
        url: '/admin/escalations/newUser', 
        // how to fetch userEmail from the form
        data: { userEmail: this.state.userEmail

         } 
        })
}
```

form snippet

```
<label for="userEmail">Email ID: </label><br/>
<input type="text" id="userEmail" name="userEmail" value={this.userEmail} placeholder="Meltwater email ID" />
```

Please provide a solution for the above question

Comment: you have to use some event like onChange and set the state value in the state object 

check my answer below

Answer (score 0):

You have to add this.setState in onChange attributes and value is this.state.userEmail  of input like this:

```
<input type="text" id="userEmail" name="userEmail" value={this.state.userEmail} placeholder="Meltwater email ID" onChange={e => this.setState({userEmail: e.target.value})}/>
```

hopefully it will work

Comment: No luck, it still returns an empty response, 
onChange{e => this.setState({userEmail: e.target.value})} shows in red when I use it, so I tried using onChange = {e => this.setState({userEmail: e.target.value})}

Comment: HTML code and axios call are in same class ? If yes, then can you try to initialise state in the class like this

constructor(){
   super()
   this.state = {
      userMail: ""
   }
}

If it will not in same class then it will nor work.

Answer (score 0):

You need to maintain state and when user enters some value, you need to fire an event that will set the value in the state and from state you can access that value in your axios request. Check the sample code below..

```
class someClass extends React.Component{
  ~~~
  ~~~
 state : {
  userEmail : ''
 }

 takeEmailValue(e) { this.setState({ userEmail: e.target.value })}

 // add the onChange event on your input field

 <label for="userEmail">Email ID: </label><br/>
 <input type="text" id="userEmail" name="userEmail" onChange={this.takeEmailValue} placeholder="Meltwater email ID" />
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your component constructor, you should declare your state like so :

```js
constructor(){
   super()
   this.state = {
      userMail: ""
   }
}
```

Once you've done that, we will create a function to update the `userMail`value.

```js
updateMail(event){
   this.setState({
      userMail: event.target.value
   }, () => console.log(this.state.userMail)
}
```

Finally, you will just need to specify this function on your input tag like so :

```
<label for="userEmail">Email ID: </label><br/>
<input type="text" id="userEmail" name="userEmail" onChange={this.updateMail.bind(this)} placeholder="Meltwater email ID" />
```

So the `updateMail` function will, as indicates its name, update the `userMail` state every time you change the value of your input.

Thanks to that, the `userMail` state will be up to date everytime you press a key on the input.

Then, you can re-use your axios method to post this value.

I hope it will help you.

Comment: How to print the value of usermail? to use it in the axio header data

Comment: You should be able to access it using the `state` react object. Because everytime you change the email input value, it will automatically update the variable `this.state.userMail`. Then you can access it using the same variable name : `this.state.userMail`

Answer (score 0):

try like this it may help you,

```
`import React, { Component } from "react";
import axios from 'axios';

class Sample extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      userEmail: ""
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    axios({
      method: "post",
      url: "/admin/escalations/newUser",
      // how to fetch userEmail from the form
      data: { userEmail: this.state.userEmail }
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { userEmail } = this.state;
    console.log(userEmail);
    return (
      <div>
        <input
          name="userEmail"
          placeholder="enter your mail"
          value={userEmail}
          onChange={e => this.setState({ userEmail: e.target.value })}
        />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Sample;`
```